# Electrons and photons at absolute zero?

Tags: electrons, temperature, low-temperature-physics

I know that molecules can't move at absolute zero (hypothetically of course). But what happens to electrons and photons?

Comment: [You can't get to absolute zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics).  The photon question is thought-provoking, though.

Comment: Do photons feel the cold ?

Comment: possibly related: http://www.livescience.com/10288-kind-light-created-physics-breakthrough.html

Comment: @count_to_10  That article blew my mind.   I would have guessed that was impossible.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by electrons or photons "moving"? They're not classical billard balls, they don't move in the classical sense in the first place.

Comment: I know they don't move like that, but how are their interactions/behavior affected?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking how an electron would behave, say, in a bit of hydrogen-ice at very very very very very close to absolute zero?   Not just electron(s), I imagine, cause asking about just electron(s) doesn't make much sense as they would repel each other and a single electron doesn't make much sense as a way to measure temperature cause it's usually measured by interaction of more than one particle.   So, at near absolute zero, molecules form into a Boise-Einstein condensate.  Is that your question, what happens to the electrons in that state?

Answer (score -2):

Even if you could cool down to absolute zero which is impossible due to third law of thermodynamics. there would still be quantum fluctuation. electron would not stop moving. it would still orbit around atom.

Heisenberg uncertainty principle states that we can never precisely know the position of an electron and momentum simultaneously. so therefore electron will not be in rest it wouldn't occupy fixed position. it would still have vibration because of small amount of uncertainty about where the position of electron is.

Hypothetically at absolute zero all photon would occupy lowest energy state. the system will still have non zero energy.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oba_RxdESSs

Comment: *"electron would not stop moving. it would still orbit around atom"* The electron doesn't orbit the atom. Quantum objects don't "move" in the classical sense, it doesn't make any sense to talk about them being "at rest" unless you define what you mean by it.

Comment: yes electron don't move like in a classical sense. By rest i meant having fixed position. @ACuriousMind